# change text on show/hide

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a some content which I want show/hide using jquery.
Till now using below code:

```
$(document).on("click",".class", function(){
     $(this).next().slideToggle("fast"); 
      });



<div class="class"  Title="Click to view/hide all" id="flip">View &#9660;</div>
      <div class="class" id="panel"><table>
      Hello!! 
      </table>
      </div>
```

I have many such view `div` created and are working inside for loop.
      My show/hide content is working fine, but I want to change text(on button) as 'show' and 'hide' whenver user clicks.
      Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [*ternary conditional operator*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/be21c7hw%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) to switch between texts.

```
 $(document).on("click",".class", function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle("fast");  
     $(this).text($(this).text() == 'view' ? 'hide all' : 'view');
  });
```

Comment: Hi Adil, Its not working as required as at 1st instance it displays as 'view' which is inside my div. but once i click 'view' after that it works fine and show as 'show all' and 'hide all'.

Comment: You have to give the two string between those you want to switch the text, It would work if you replace show all with view. Check my updated answer